# How to implement WS-Policy with Java and Axis2?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, apache-axis

I'm doing an exercise using Java and Axis2 to implement some WS-* framework.
The only part I had a "tutorial" of sort is implementing the WS-Security framework with Timestamp, Encryption and Signature.

I have a service folder for the server-side that contains my security keys, the java class with the method to call (a simple sum) and the PWCallback class that it's used for user/password auth. 
Inside there's the META-INF folder that contains the services.xml file.

The client folder has the java client, the PWCallback class and an axis2.xml file.

The axis2.xml and services.xml were already there, I just commented out the part to enable the timestamp etc.

Now my problem is that I don't know how to integrate ws-policy and ws-secureconnection too.

Reading online I see a different way of writing the xml file and I don't know where to start.

I'll post some code now:

Axis2.xml

```
<axisconfig name="AxisJava2.0">
<!-- Engage the security module -->
<module ref="rampart"/>

<parameter name="OutflowSecurity">
    <action>
        <items>Timestamp Signature Encrypt</items>
        <user>John</user>
        <passwordCallbackClass>client.PWCallback</passwordCallbackClass>
        <signaturePropFile>axis-repo\\conf\\security.properties</signaturePropFile>
        <signatureKeyIdentifier>SKIKeyIdentifier</signatureKeyIdentifier>
        <encryptionKeyIdentifier>SKIKeyIdentifier</encryptionKeyIdentifier>
        <encryptionUser>John</encryptionUser>
        <signatureParts>Body</signatureParts>
        <optimizeParts>//xenc:EncryptedData/xenc:CipherData/xenc:CipherValue</optimizeParts>
    </action>
</parameter>
<parameter name="InflowSecurity">
    <action>
        <items>Timestamp Signature Encrypt</items>
        <user>John</user>
        <passwordCallbackClass>client.PWCallback</passwordCallbackClass>
        <signaturePropFile>axis-repo\\conf\\security.properties</signaturePropFile>
        <signatureKeyIdentifier>SKIKeyIdentifier</signatureKeyIdentifier>
        <encryptionKeyIdentifier>SKIKeyIdentifier</encryptionKeyIdentifier>
        <encryptionUser>John</encryptionUser>
        <signatureParts>Body</signatureParts>
        <optimizeParts>//xenc:EncryptedData/xenc:CipherData/xenc:CipherValue</optimizeParts>
    </action>
</parameter>

<!-- ================================================= -->
<!-- Parameters -->
<!-- ================================================= -->
<parameter name="hotdeployment"
locked="false">true</parameter>
<parameter name="hotupdate" locked="false">false</parameter>
<parameter name="enableMTOM" locked="false">true</parameter>
<!-- Uncomment this to enable REST support -->
<!-- <parameter name="enableREST"
locked="false">true</parameter>-->
<parameter name="userName" locked="false">admin</parameter>
<parameter name="password" locked="false">axis2</parameter>
<!-- ================================================= -->
<!-- Message Receivers -->
<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--This is the Deafult Message Receiver for the system ,
if you want to have MessageReceivers for -->
<!--all the other MEP implement it and add the correct entry
to here, so that you can refer from-->
<!--any operation -->
<!--Note : You can ovride this for particular service by
adding the same element with your requirement-->
<messageReceivers>
<messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only"
class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
<messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"
class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>
</messageReceivers>
<!-- ================================================= -->
<!-- Transport Ins -->
<!-- ================================================= -->
<transportReceiver name="http"
class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SimpleHTTPServer">
<parameter name="port" locked="false">6060</parameter>
<!--If you want to give your own host address for EPR
generation-->
<!--uncommet following paramter , and set as you required.-->
<!--<parameter name="hostname"
locked="false">http://myApp.com/ws</parameter>-->
</transportReceiver>
<transportReceiver name="tcp"
class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPServer">
<parameter name="port" locked="false">6061</parameter>
<!--If you want to give your own host address for EPR
generation-->
<!--uncommet following paramter , and set as you required.-->
<!--<parameter name="hostname"
locked="false">tcp://myApp.com/ws</parameter>-->
</transportReceiver>
<!-- ================================================= -->
<!-- Transport Outs -->
<!-- ================================================= -->
<transportSender name="tcp"
class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender"/>
<transportSender name="local"
class="org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender"/>
<!--<transportSender name="jms"
class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender"/>-->
<transportSender name="http"
class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
<parameter name="PROTOCOL"
locked="false">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
<parameter name="Transfer-Encoding"
locked="false">chunked</parameter>
</transportSender>
<transportSender name="https"
class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
<parameter name="PROTOCOL"
locked="false">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
<parameter name="Transfer-Encoding"
locked="false">chunked</parameter>
</transportSender>
<!-- ================================================= -->
<!-- Phases -->
<!-- ================================================= -->
<phaseOrder type="InFlow">
        <!--   Global phases    -->
         <phase name="Transport">
            <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Transport"/>
            </handler>

            <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Transport"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="Security"/>
        <phase name="PreDispatch"/>
        <phase name="Dispatch" class="org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase">
            <handler name="AddressingBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.AddressingBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Dispatch"/>
            </handler>

            <handler name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Dispatch"/>
            </handler>

            <handler name="InstanceDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.engine.InstanceDispatcher">
                <order phase="Dispatch"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <!--   Global phases   -->
        <!--   After the Dispatch phase module author or service author can add any phase he wants    -->
        <phase name="OperationInPhase"/>
    </phaseOrder>
    <phaseOrder type="OutFlow">
        <!--   user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="OperationOutPhase"/>
        <!--  Global phases  -->
        <!--  these phases will run irrespective of the service  -->
        <phase name="MessageOut"/>
        <phase name="PolicyDetermination"/>
                <phase name="Security"/>
    </phaseOrder>
    <phaseOrder type="InFaultFlow">
        <phase name="PreDispatch"/>
        <phase name="Dispatch" class="org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase">
            <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Dispatch"/>
            </handler>

            <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Dispatch"/>
            </handler>

            <handler name="AddressingBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.AddressingBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Dispatch"/>
            </handler>

            <handler name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Dispatch"/>
            </handler>
            <handler name="InstanceDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.engine.InstanceDispatcher">
                <order phase="Dispatch"/>
            </handler>
            <handler name="SecurityInHandler" class="org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver"> 
                    <order phase="Security"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="Security">
            <handler name="SecurityInHandler" class="org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver"> 
                <order phase="Security"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
          <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="OperationInFaultPhase"/>
    </phaseOrder>
    <phaseOrder type="OutFaultFlow">
        <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="OperationOutFaultPhase"/>
                <phase name="Security"/>
        <phase name="PolicyDetermination"/>
        <phase name="MessageOut"/>
    </phaseOrder>
</axisconfig>
```

Services.xml

```
<service name="SecureService">
<description>
Secure Service
</description>
<parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">SecureService</parameter>

<parameter name="InflowSecurity">
    <action>
        <items>Timestamp Signature Encrypt</items>
        <user>John</user>
        <passwordCallbackClass>PWCallback</passwordCallbackClass>
        <signaturePropFile>security.properties</signaturePropFile>
    </action>
</parameter>

<parameter name="OutflowSecurity">
    <action>
        <items>Timestamp Signature Encrypt</items>
        <user>John</user>
        <passwordCallbackClass>PWCallback</passwordCallbackClass>
        <signaturePropFile>security.properties</signaturePropFile>
    </action>
</parameter>

<operation name="binary">
<messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</operation>
</service>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you need but you can programmatically load WS-Policy to be used by rampart module. Just get ServiceClient object from your client stub and then do something like this:

```
serviceClient.getAxisService().getPolicySubject().attachPolicyComponent(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY, loadPolicy(path_to_your_ws_policy));
```

To make secure connection with your client you could add custom protocol handler though I'm not sure if there's no better way of doing this.

```
Protocol customProtocolHandler = new Protocol("https", factory, 443); // factory is ProtocolSocketFactory - you may try to use or extend SSLProtocolSocketFactory from axis2
serviceClient.getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CUSTOM_PROTOCOL_HANDLER, customProtocolHandler);
```

On the server side you may put your service in tomcat and enable TLS as described here: http://shivendra-tripathi.blogspot.com/2010/11/enabling-ssl-for-axis2-service-and.html (there are some instructions for client too).